# openlayers 6 fill feature with custom image

Tags: javascript, openlayers-6

```html
new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource(),
  style: new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)', width: 2 }),
    image:  new Icon({src: '/images/crop.jpg',opacity:1,scale:1})
})
```

this suppose to make all features polygons filled with image located at /images/crop.jpg
but in real life it just draws transparent polygons.

is there something Im missing?

thanks!

Comment: Do you want to fill with repeat pattern of icons for example https://codesandbox.io/s/canvas-gradient-pattern-ckiu0 or did you want one icon at the center of each polygon (similar to a label)?

Comment: is there possibility not to repeat, but stretch image?